# How do you remove an extension from an X509?

Tags: c, openssl, x509

I am creating an api for modifying `X509` certificates in C and I want to add a way to remove an extension (e.g. `subjectNameAlt`). How would I do this via the OpenSSL API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul's answer is freeing a pointer returned from X509_get_ext, which the documentation explicitly says not to do.. As stated by [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/X509_get_ext.html):

> `X509v3_get_ext()` [and `X509_get_ext()`] retrieves extension loc from `x`.
>   The index loc can take any value from 0 to `X509_get_ext_count(x) - 1`.
>   The returned extension is an internal pointer which **must not be
>   freed up by the application**.

The correct way to free the extension is as follows.

```
int idx = X509_get_ext_by_NID( cert, nid, -1 ); //get the index
X509_EXTENSION *ext = X509_get_ext(cert, idx); //get the extension
if (ext != NULL){ //check that the extension was found
    X509_EXTENSION *tmp = X509_delete_ext(cert, idx); //delete the extension
    X509_EXTENSION_free(tmp); //free the memory
}
```

Comment: Would chacham's answer have been correct 4+ years ago?

Comment: @chacham15 They're *not* identical. Your answer is freeing a pointer returned from `X509_get_ext`, which the documentation explicitly says *not* to do. Frankly, both of these answers could use some work, because the `X509_get_ext` calls in both are pointless. You can simply invoke `X509_get_ext_by_NID` with the appropriate nid, and if the index returned is >=0,  do what is in the if-block of *this* answer. The actual extension fetch is unnecessary; the delete will return it anyway (detached from the cert), and only *then* should it be free'd.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `X509_NAME_delete_entry ()` function for this:

> X509_NAME_delete_entry() deletes an entry from name at position loc.
>   The deleted entry is returned and must be freed up.

Man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/x509_name_delete_entry

**Edit:**

To actually get and delete an extension, you can use the following function:

```
X509_EXTENSION *X509_delete_ext(X509 *x, int loc);
```

**Example:**

```
int idx = X509_get_ext_by_NID( cert, nid, -1 ); //get the index
X509_EXTENSION *ext = X509_get_ext(cert, idx); //get the extension
if (ext != NULL){ //check that the extension was found
    X509_delete_ext(cert, idx); //delete the extension
    X509_EXTENSION_free(ext); //free the memory
}
```

Comment: Thats for the distinguished name, isnt it? subjectNameAlt isnt part of the distinguished name, its part of the x509v3 extensions.

Comment: yes, you are right. X509_NAME_delete_entry () works only with certificate information fields.

Comment: Updated my comment with the example how to work with certificate extensions. Hope it helps !

Comment: I updated your code based on the `X509_delete_ext`. The problem was that `X509_get_ext_d2i` returns a new memory structure specific to the type of the nid and therefore would be a pain to free (especially since we dont need it). Thanks though! It was a great help!

Comment: Side question: do you know the equivalent function of `X509_delete_ext` for `X509_REQ`s?