# How do you modify an extension from an X509?

Tags: c, openssl, x509

I am creating an api for modifying `X509` certificates in C and I want to add a way to modify an extension. For example, add another DNS entry to `subjectNameAlt` so that it would be `DNS:example.com,DNS:example2.com` instead of just `DNS:example.com` . The reason that deleting and re-adding is bad is because I then have to reparse the extension (which is difficult) and I would rather just add a piece of information. How would I do this via the OpenSSL API?

I tried to simply reuse the add code:

```
ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, &ctx, NID_subject_alt_name, "DNS:new.dns.example");
if (!ex)
    return;
X509_add_ext(cert,ex,-1);
X509_EXTENSION_free(ex);
```

But after running that, the extension isnt found at all (even if i try to add another new one).

Comment: This a very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978758/how-do-you-remove-an-extension-from-an-x509) you asked 10 minutes earlier. Consider editing the original rather than asking a new question.

Comment: @luserdroog they are similar but involve different methods in the OpenSSL api and have different goals

Comment: Ok. I'm just saying that *it looks like* a revision of the previous Q. You might want to make them *more different looking* to avoid others trying to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
  demos/x509/mkcert.c
  demos/x509/selfsign.c
  demos/x509/mkreq.c
```

in your openssl distribution. I suspect that you are not setting up your context; or you are making an assumption in that some i2d/etc is called behind the scene when you say 'is not found at all'. Note that X509_sign() and their ilk do create a lot of this. If you are not calling anything -then do not expect any of those to be created.